# User Data from Facebook WITHOUT SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have the access token from the user, and I want to retrive the data from their profile. I am  working on Unity3D c# therefore I can not use any SDK. 
Is there a way of getting it trough a graph request?

I've already tried with

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=00000000000000|AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

but throws me an error like this..

```
  "message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.",
```

When I ask for permissions I ask the user to allow me the publish_stream and to access profile data. 
How do I get an active access token? I just want the UserID.

Thanks for your answers, and sorry for my terrible english.

Comment: For anyone interested in this, I answered myself at the bottom of this page. :)

Answer (score 2):

So I wanted ti get the User UserAgent Token the only thing that you must do is add that parameter to the Access URL in my case

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?type=user_agent&client_id=000000000000000&redirect_uri=http://yourRedirectdomain.com&scope=user_photos,email,user_birthday,offline_access,plublish_stream
```

Facebook will redirect you to the redirect_uri URL, and the access token will be given in form of a hash. Extra Tip: Yo have to access the Hashed token vía Javascript,

```
var hash = document.location.hash;
 var n=hash.split("=");
```

This is one method, Im sure there is a better one.

Thank everybody for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

you're Graph Call / HTTP request looks about right.

I'm guessing, based on the error, that the access token has expired.
Normally, they last for about 1-2 hours since the last time they were used. (If i recall correctly). So, a user will start using a website, and the website can make graph calls with the access token while the user is actually using the website for that session, but the token will expire soon after that.

However, you can also ask Facebook for a longer lasting access_token, which will last for approximately 60 days.
Check here for some info :: http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

As it stands, trying to find this info through browsing the developer docs in Facebook is rather difficult, if not impossible. :-/

Comment: The thing here is that I can create post walls with that token, Im sure it hasn't expired. I can do that with the Javascript SDK, the token works! :(

Comment: To me, that error message and the form you use for the access token indicates that you're using an *app* access token, not a user access token, which doesn't have a pipe (`|`).

Comment: Yes I am using the token that belongs to the application but refers (targets I don't know the english word) refers to the user... It is the only token I have since the user created it in my app... Any ideas?

Comment: Where are you creating wall posts to? A user's newsfeed, or to a page, or somewhere else?

Comment: To the user wall,  with Javascript I don't have to add anything else, that's why thought that was the correct Token.

Comment: Can you post URL you're using to post to the user's wall? I suspect you're using their ID in the graph call, instead of /me/?
Ah, just noticed you're other answer. Glad it's OK for you now! :)

Answer (score 0):

You *can’t* query the API for `/me` with an **app** access token, since the API has no way of knowing who “me” is supposed to be.

Only **user** access tokens contain the info which user id they apply to, and hence only those can be used to query `/me` successfully.

Comment: How can I get a user access token then? When they approve my app, how can I call the user access token? Thanks for your help.